# Can you set the MachineKey programmatically?

Tags: asp.net, web-config

In ASP.NET can you set the `machineKey` settings programmatically?

The web app that we use stores sensitive info encrypted in a database, so if we could put the decryptionKey there it would be handy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No; the machineKey element must be set via config.  However, web.config can itself be encrypted, which helps minimize risk of cryptographic key disclosure if an attacker ever gets access to the config file.  (This same process can be used to protect SQL connection strings and pretty much any other sensitive config element you wish.)  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtkwfdky(v=VS.100).aspx for a walkthrough on enabling this.

Comment: is there no way to modify the web.config in code prior to the app starting? having this in an environment variable would be much better and more dynamic then having to have an encrypted config file on all the servers

Comment: Its possible. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. I got success using this code in ConsoleApplication:

```
private static void ChangeWebConfig(string validationKey, string decryptionKey, string webConfigPath)
{
    ExeConfigurationFileMap configFileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
    configFileMap.ExeConfigFilename = webConfigPath;
    System.Configuration.Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configFileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
    MachineKeySection section = (MachineKeySection)config.GetSection("system.web/machineKey");
    section.ValidationKey = validationKey;
    section.DecryptionKey = decryptionKey;
    config.Save();
}
```

Comment: This is changing the underlying file thought right? would the application need to restart to read it in again to see the updates?

Comment: I dont know. But the ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration gives you the Configuration instance with the data contained in file, so, if u need it, just call this methot, I gues.